# Default implementation for indexer

Tags: c#, interface, traits, default-implementation

What is wrong with my code below or, alternatively, what is the point of a default indexer implementation if it isn't used by default?

```
public interface IFoo {
    string this[string key] { get => "Default string index getter"; }
}


// Implementor
public class Foo : IFoo {}

// Usage
Foo myFoo = new();
var bar = myFoo["KEY"];

--> Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'Baz.Foo'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're referencing it by class, not by the interface.

It works fine if you use:

```
// Usage
IFoo myFoo = new Foo();
var bar = myFoo["KEY"];
```

Why doesn't the class use the interface defaults, by default? Microsoft says:

> That cast from SampleCustomer to ICustomer is necessary. The
> SampleCustomer class doesn't need to provide an implementation for
> ComputeLoyaltyDiscount; that's provided by the ICustomer interface.
> However, the SampleCustomer class doesn't inherit members from its
> interfaces. That rule hasn't changed. In order to call any method
> declared and implemented in the interface, the variable must be the
> type of the interface, ICustomer in this example.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interface-implementation/default-interface-methods-versions